# SerializationException on Catel auto create of ViewModel with EF Entity Model

Tags: entity-framework, catel

When Catel attempts to auto create an instance of the ViewModel class belonging to a view I get a SerializationException complaining that System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies is not expected.
The Model is an EF 6.1 Entity (inherits from ModelBase) and I am using Catel 3.9.
How do I prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: this all applies to Catel 4.0 (latest prerelease versions, since that is stable and has much improvements).*

Catel serializes the model for the purpose of the IEditableObject implementation. When using the Model attribute, it tries to serialize the members. You have 2 options:

1. Use the [Model(SupportedIEditableObject = false)] (but you will
   lose the "automatic cancel" functionality
2. Decorate the failing members with [ExcludeFromSerialization] or
   use a custom serializer modifier

Comment: Thankyou very much for your quick response. I quickly tested alternative 1 and so far it seems to work fine. But what do you mean with "automatic cancel" functionality?

Comment: Automatic cancel means: if you use a Model attribute, it will store current values. If CancelViewModel is called, the changes on the model are automatically reverted for you (using IEditableObject).