# SerializationException and lazy load on Catel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, catel

I create project whith catel 5.2 and Orc.EntityFramework 2.0.1. The Model is an EF 6.2 Entity (inherits from ModelBase). When i trying to open modal winodw, and create my object which decorated [Model] and is bound DB, throw "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies is not expected".
I found two solutions to this problem:

1)Ban create proxy in constructor DbContex

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

2)Use the

```
[Model(SupportedIEditableObject = false)]
```

But I do not want to lose the "automatic cancel" functionality

So, How to do it correctly?

Second problem. My model it has two objects, and they relate to each other as many-to-many. So, lezy load don't work. In order to download the object by reference, I must use .Include("") on repository. For example

```
var projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>(projectRepositiry.GetAll().Include("Employees"));
```

If I do not use .Include() and then try to access the collection Employees in project in code, collection is empty! Although it should be loaded!
Well, it can be taken when I need all the objects, but if I want to download only one object?

If i use

```
var project = projectRepositiry.GetByKey(1);
```

Collection employees in project(virtual reference) is empty. And I can not use .Include() on GetByKey(). How to make "lazy load" work?

Comment: One question per post please. If you edit your question maybe you should also clarify what you mean by "automatic cancel". Is that a Catel concept? And how is it related to `ProxyCreationEnabled`?

Comment: "automatic cancel" found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928026/serializationexception-on-catel-auto-create-of-viewmodel-with-ef-entity-model

Comment: How is it related to ProxyCreationEnabled? Apparently Catel wrong working whith proxy object, which creates EF as stubs for virtual links. Or maybe not)) I dont know) But ProxyCreationEnabled = false; work